# Unique Validation doesn't work

Tags: yii2

The problem appears when i try to validate in my form a Document of identity as unique, doesn't work but when i pulse create button, the unique valide the form but with another view.. my form is a dynamic form .
This is my Dynamic form:

```
 <?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use frontend\models\Oficinas;
use frontend\models\Departamento;
use yii\helpers\Url;
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model frontend\models\Solicitante */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>
<div class="solicitante-form">
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'id_oficina')->dropDownList(                ArrayHelper::map(Oficinas::find()->all(),'id_oficina','descripcion_oficina'),
                [
                    'prompt'=>'Seleccione la Oficina ...',
                    'onchange'=>'
                        $.post( "'.Url::toRoute('departamento/lists?id=').'"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
                            $( "select#solicitante-id_departamento" ).html( data );
                    });'
         ]); ?>                

    <?= $form->field($model, 'id_departamento')->dropDownList(
                ArrayHelper::map( Departamento::find()->all(), 'id_departamento','descripcion_depar'),
                [
                    'prompt'=>'Seleccione el Departamento ...',
         ]); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'cedula_solicitante')->textInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'nombre')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'apellido')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'telefonos')->textInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'correo_electronico')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Crear' : 'Modificar', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

and my Controller:

```
<?php
namespace frontend\controllers;
use Yii;
use frontend\models\Solicitante;
use frontend\models\SolicitanteSearch;
use frontend\models\GruposTecnicos;
use frontend\models\Model;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use common\models\HtmlHelpers;
use frontend\models\SolicitudServicio;
use frontend\models\SolicitudServicioSearch;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use common\components\AccessRule;
use common\models\User;
/**
 * SolicitanteController implements the CRUD actions for Solicitante model.
 */
class SolicitanteController extends Controller
{
    public function behaviors()
     {
        return [         
        'verbs' => [
                   'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                   'actions' => [
                       'delete' => ['post'],
                   ],
               ],
               'access' => [
                   'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                   // We will override the default rule config with the new AccessRule class
                   'ruleConfig' => [
                       'class' => AccessRule::className(),
                   ],
                   'only' => ['index','create', 'update', 'delete','view','prueba'],
                   'rules' => [
                       [
                           'actions' => ['index','create','view','update','delete','prueba'],
                           'allow' => true,
                           // Allow users, moderators and admins to create
                           'roles' => [                                                           
                               User::ROLE_ADMINISTRADOR,
                               User::ROLE_SUPER_USUARIO,
                           ],
                         ],
                          [
                           'actions' => ['index','create','view','update','prueba'],
                           'allow' => true,
                           // Allow users, moderators and admins to create
                           'roles' => [                                                           
                               User::ROLE_OPERADOR,
                           ],
                         ],
                          [
                           'actions' => ['index'],
                           'allow' => true,
                           // Allow users, moderators and admins to create
                           'roles' => [                                                           
                               User::ROLE_COORDINADOR,
                               User::ROLE_TECNICO,
                           ],
                         ],                                            
                       ],                                          
             'denyCallback'  => function ($rule,$user) {
                  //Yii::$app->user->loginRequired();
                  Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'DISCULPE USTED NO TIENE LOS PERMISOS NECESARIOS PARA REALIZAR ESTA ACCION.');
                  return $this->goHome();
            },  
               ],                   
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Solicitante models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
      $rol=Yii::$app->user->identity->role;
      if($rol=='ADMINISTRADOR' || $rol=='SUPER_USUARIO' || $rol=='OPERADOR'){

        $searchModel = new SolicitanteSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);     
      }else{
        $searchModel = new SolicitanteSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        return $this->render('index2', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            ]);
          }
    }
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }   
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Solicitante();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) &&  $model->save() ) {          
             // var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post());die;

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id_solicitante]);
        } else {
            return $this->renderAjax('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Here an img of the Error 1:
http://s8.postimg.org/71totbzat/Error1.jpg

Error 2:
http://s14.postimg.org/jiftd3z7l/Error2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You just change your form submit button name

```
<?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Crear' : 'Modificar', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

To

```
<?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Modificar', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

And also change in your controller `actionCreate()` like..

```
return $this->renderAjax('create', [
            'model' => $model,
]);
```

To

```
return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
]);
```

Comment: Ty...The problem was at render.. but now if i change renderAjax for Render look what's happen.. http://s14.postimg.org/d378gr8y9/Error_Img.jpg ... but with RenderAjax. :http://s18.postimg.org/p3nkwwag9/Error_Img2.jpg ... i want the view what shows me Without RenderAjax (Unique Validation) .. but when i push the button create Without ajax the form Dynamic shows me.. the form more The menu.. you know what You know,¿what  may be the error ?